# C# Split by String[] Delimiter Match Exact Word Only

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have string where its value should be splitted by string delimiter. For example my delimiter is "at", I want to split only the string value by exact "at" keyword. Below is my sample string value

```
 var sampleStr= "at Metadata at quota at what at batter";
```

If I use the code below, the words with "at" in them are also splitted.

```
var result= sampleStr.Split(new string[] { "at" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The result that I want is an array that if combined will be "Metadata quota what batter".

Please help.

Comment: Change your string to be `atMetadataatquotaatwhatatbatter` or change your delimiter to be `" at "` including the spaces. Or if whitespace is not important, call `Trim()` before splitting

Comment: @DGibbs I can't change them. My sample string value is just a sample but my actual data is a StackTrace of an Exception. So omitting space I think not the solution. Forexample few lines of StackTrace System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at

Comment: If the pattern is always "[...]​\r\n at [...]", couldn't you simply split on "\r\n at "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 splitted = Regex.Split(text,@"\bat\s*\b");
```

\b denotes any word-boundary. \s* will match the whitespace characters after "at".

```
splitted : string [] = [|""; "Metadata "; "quota "; "what "; "batter"|]
```

If you **don't need a Empty Space** then try like below...

```
List<string> splitted = Regex.Split(phrase, @"\bat\s*\b",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

splitted : string [] = [| "Metadata "; "quota "; "what "; "batter"|]
```

Comment: If you want to have it ignore case, you can use this overload http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byy2946e.aspx and apply RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
IEnumerable<string> wordsWithoutAt = sampleStr.Split()
    .Where(w => !StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(w, "at"));
string result = string.Join(" " , wordsWithoutAt);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/mITFGo)

If the case matters replace the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` part with `!= "at"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any reliable solution on this, as this is very *language* and your string possible structure specific.

To make it *easier* you may think of splitting by `" at "` (`at` with spaces in front and back), but this will not reolve all possible problems by the way.

Example:

`"I was loooking at the tree"`, will fail, as "at" here is not delimeter but a *word* inside a real phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the surrounding whitespace....

First of all, wrap your original text in some whitespace to cope with "at" at the start and/or end:

```
sampleStr = " " + sampleStr + " ";
```

Then do you split like so:

```
var result = sampleStr.Split(new string[] { " at " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then you have the result you want.